# Adding a Public Key to known_hosts File

Tags: openssh

I have downloaded the ECDSA public key (`ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub`) from another machine. I want to add the key to my local `known_hosts` file before connecting to it via SSH. How can I do that manually (without comparing MD5 hashes on the screen)?

I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 on my local machine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Manual page for [`sshd(8)`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8) describes the format of `known_hosts` file:

> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers (optional), hostnames, bits, exponent, modulus, comment.  The fields are separated by spaces.

If your public key for your host looks like this:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA1234.....=
```

So just putting this line into your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file:

```
your.host.name,0.0.0.0 ssh-rsa AAAA1234.....=
```

where you will exchange hostname and ip for your host.

Now it depends if you have `ssh` option `HashKnownHosts` turned on. If not, you are done. Otherwise (e.g. on current Ubuntu releases) you will need to hash this file using `ssh-keygen -H -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: What is the significance of the equals sign at the end of `ssh-rsa AAAA1234.....=`? I opened up my public key and it does not end with an equals sign, instead the format looks like:

 `ssh-rsa AAAA1234....  user@hostname`. How would I insert that into my `known_hosts` file?

Comment: @wheeler Insert it to the known hosts as it is. The equal sign is just a padding of base64 encoding.

Comment: why isnt there just a simple cmd to add a public key to known_hosts? If I got it from an other trusted source, its much better than using the often proposed ssh-keyscan which depends on trust-on-first-use